# Как позиционировать текст поверх изображения не используя абсолютное позиционирование?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как позиционировать текст поверх изображения (изображение НЕ фоновое) т.е. один слой поверх другого, Не используя комбинацию "Родитель - position: relative; потомок - position: absolute" ?

Comment: а чем не нравится указанная комбинация?

Comment: можете еще использовать псевдоэлементы before и after но там тоже позиционирование будет через absolute

Comment: `z-index` && `display:flex;`

Answer (score 1):

Можно классу придать свойство "position: relative;"
И далее указывать позицию относительно текущего местоположения.
То есть, "top: -30px;" - значит, что элемент нужно поднять на верх на 30 пикселей. Аналогично вправо, вниз, влево.

```css
figure {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: smaller;
  text-indent: 0;
}

figcaption{
  position: relative;
  top: -70px;
  color: #fff;
}

img.scaled {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <p><img class=scaled src="https://media.archonia.com/images/samples/38/96/43896_s0.jpg" alt="St. Tropez">
    <figcaption>Saint Tropez and its fort in the evening sun</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

могу предложить 2 решения:

1. Использовать отрицательный отступ для блока с текстом

   text

   div {
     max-width: 400px;
   }
   img {
     width: 100%;
   }
   .text {
     margin-top: -150px;
     color: #fff;
   }

   2. Использовать трансформацию для блока с текстом

.text {
      transform: translateY(-150px);
    }

Answer (score 0):

кстати, в интернетах видел очень много вариантов через `position`, но никто не предложил вариант через `display`. надеюсь я смогу кому-то помочь. Основной класс для позиционирования текста на изображении .flex-col-c-m И да, этот вариант **НЕ ЛОМАЕТ АДАПТИВ** как это делает `position: absolute;`

Если кому надо без `position: absolute;`

```css
.wrap-slick1{
  position: relative;
}

.item-slick1 {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.item-slick1 {
  height: 100vh;
}

.sizefull {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.flex-col-c-m {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -o-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

h1 {color:white;}
```

```html
<div class="item-slick1" style="background-image: url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/1219682/pub_5eaa7423102eee24419d5607_5eaa74d77e79087ec3668df9/scale_1200); border-radius: 10px;">
  <div class="wrap-content-slide1 sizefull flex-col-c-m">
    <h1>
      Text
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```